# Retain formatting of a Double value - Java

Tags: java, formatting, double

I am using Poi to create Excel workbooks in Java.  My raw data comes in as a string.  I need to format the data to enter two decimal places into the cell where the number is being written.  I use *Double.parseDouble()* to convert the string to numeric and then use *DecimalFormat* to format the numeric as a string.  Another call to *Double.parseDouble()* to return the value to numeric (the cell where it is going is formatted numeric, so I can't use the string value) and I should be good.  Problem is, that second call to **Double.parseDouble()** truncates any trailing zeroes off from the right of the decimal point.  Anybody have an idea as to how I can coerce this value to read as, say, 1.50 rather than 1.5?

Comment: Wait, so you're doing String -> Double -> String -> Double?

And it's the last String -> Double that's changing your formatting?

Do you always want 2 digits, or do you want however many the string came in with?

Comment: I always want two decimals.  If the string comes in as 1.5, I want it to read 1.50.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears we are at an impasse.  As Mario pointed out, doubles are managed as binary and there is no way to format the binary *as a double*, except to convert it to a string with DecimalFormat, which is no longer a double.  I explained this to my boss and he's ok with the solution of taking the raw double, so I'm closing this issue.  Thanks to all for your help and support.

regards,
Mike

Comment: You can explicitly set an existing Cell in POI to use String type and retrieve that value as String instead of numeric (double). From there, you can use the formatting suggestions described in the other posts.

Answer (score 3):

*`I always want two decimals.`*

Solution: *Always apply specific decimal format pattern.*

**Sample code snippet**:

```
//java.text.DecimalFormat df = new java.text.DecimalFormat( "###0.00" );  
java.text.DecimalFormat df = new java.text.DecimalFormat();  
df.applyPattern( "###0.00" ); // always two decimals  

double dbl = 1.50d ;  

// prints: dbl =  1.5
System.out.println( "dbl = " + dbl );  

// prints: df.format( 1.5 ) = 1.50
System.out.println ( "df.format( " + dbl + " ) = " + df.format( dbl ) );
```

**UPDATE**:
OK, from your posting, I understand that you are trying to fill the numeric formatted cell only to print or show up with two decimal positions. You know by default all numeric fields are interpreted omitting trailing zeros. To achieve your requirement, you may require to use [`CellFormat`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/format/CellFormat.html) and/or [`DataFormatter`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html) on your contextual [`Cell`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html) object, but when said `Format`, it is a `String` again.

I didn't try the following code but may help you.

```
DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();
dataFormatter.setDefaultNumberFormat( instanceOfDesiredDecimalFormat );  
// or  
// dataFormatter.setExcelStyleRoundingMode( instanceOfDesiredDecimalFormat );  

// apply this format on the cell you want
dataFormatter.formatCellValue( instanceOfNumericCellInContext );
```

Comment: DecimalFormat returns a string.  I need to return a double.  That's why, in the original question, I have to use Double.parseDouble twice.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually doing nothing in most part of the code you described. You might as well just return Double.parseDouble(inputString). Doubles are stored in binary format and the leadin/trailing zeros make no sense. Perhaps the [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class is something for you.

Comment: Great suggestion.  I am limited in that Poi will only take a double value in a numerically formatted field, but I think under other circumstances your reply would have solved my situation.

Comment: @MikePreston I'm afraid I don't know POI, but surely there must be an actual solution... Try asking on a POI-specific forum?